# How to learn vsts previous task condition

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Using VSTS online and trying to do gated check. Want to learn if the previous task failed.

How do we write that custom condition?

Answer (score 0):

There already has the condition **Only when a previous task has failed** (`failed()`). So you can use this item for your current task, so that only if previous task is failed, current task will be executed.

[image]

For more detail for custom condtions, you can refer [Specify conditions for running a task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/conditions).